# get id of current item in jcarousel

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im looking to highlight the current dot pagination button in my carousel, so im attempting to add a class to whatever particular one is being used, for some reason this doesnt work, its adds the inactive class with no problems but doesnt add the active, so it doesnt seem to be recognising i.
Im only new to js, am I missing something obvious?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#right-carousel').jcarousel({
    start: 1, // Configuration goes here
    wrap: "circular",
    scroll: 1,
    auto:3,
    vertical:true,

    itemFirstInCallback: {
    onBeforeAnimation: function(carousel, item, index, action, c, o, i, s ) {
        if (carousel_2) {
            carousel_2[action]();
        }
        i = (i - 1) % $('#right-carousel li').size();
        jQuery('.jcarousel-pagination a').addClass('inactive');
            jQuery('.jcarousel-pagination a:eq('+i+')').removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');


    jQuery('.jcarousel-pagination a').bind('click', function() {
    carousel.scroll(jQuery.jcarousel.intval(jQuery(this).attr('id')));
    return false;
        }); 

            }
        }

    });

});
```

Just to add one more detail, the main issue seems to be that i is not defined even when I declare it inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

This code should work if you put your pagination dots(.jcarousel-pagination) into the jcarousel container. It should also work with multiple carousels:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel, state) {
    jQuery(carousel.container).find('.jcarousel-pagination a').bind('click', function() {
      carousel.scroll(parseInt(jQuery(this).attr('id')));
      return false;
    });

    jQuery(carousel.container).find('#mycarousel-next').bind('click', function() {
      carousel.next();
      return false;
    });

    jQuery(carousel.container).find('#mycarousel-prev').bind('click', function() {
      carousel.prev();
      return false;
    });
}

function mycarousel_visibleCallback(carousel, item, index, state){
  var dot = jQuery(carousel.container).find(".jcarousel-pagination a#" + index);
  dot.siblings().removeClass("active");
  dot.addClass("active");
}


jQuery('#right-carousel').jcarousel({
    start: 1, // Configuration goes here
    wrap: "circular",
    scroll: 1,
    auto:3,
    vertical:true,
    initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback,
    itemVisibleInCallback: mycarousel_visibleCallback
    });

});
```